# Is serialisation/deserialisation possible with Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, serialization, silverlight-4.0

I realize easily serialisation and deserialisation of my objet with XML file.
I am wondering if it is possible to do that with binary file.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can convert it to XML, I would convert the binary file to a base 64 string.

```
    Stream fileStream = file.OpenRead();
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
    byte[] binaryData = new Byte[stream.Length]; 
    long bytesRead = stream.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)stream.Length); 

    string base64String = 
            System.Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData, 
                                          0, 
                                          binaryData.Length); 

    return base64String;
```